# Suitable Eclipse Release?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new in java and want to install Eclipse. What's appropriate version should i install as

> ```
> java version "1.6.0_38" 
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 1.6.0_38-b05) Java HotSpot(TM) 
> Client VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
> jdk1.6.0_38
> jre1.6.0_38
> ```

Comment: Indigo worked for me with JDK 1.6. Didn't try with Kepler. Don't even try Juno. It's just so broken.

Comment: You could try Kepler too. It doesn't cost you anything. Except of time needed to download that software.

Comment: Kepler is good for me, as was Indigo

Comment: Thanks I'll try one of them but I'm using Ubuntu not windows and I'm new in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install any eclipse version.There is not jdk version required for installing eclipse

Comment: is there no problem in Indigo ? and what about Juno . just i saw a problem with some releases .

Comment: @user3188912 It will work fine.For running eclipse it will look for javaw.exe(if using windows).

Comment: and what about Ubuntu .. !?

Comment: @user3188912 Not aware of ubuntu.I have earlier worked in oracle linux and there i was using eclipse indigo and then later shifted to kepler to work in javafx

Comment: what's javafx ? is there a platform like eclipse ?

Comment: @user3188912 for building gui

Comment: Thanks , sorry for my question as I'm new in java

Comment: @user3188912 no problem.Always ready to help.You can ask me any queries

Comment: Many Thanks ,I'll install release and hope work fine ,i accepted your answser as i'm not able to vote up cause must have 15 reputation